# Is my CentOS library multiarch? And what does that mean?

Tags: linux, centos, libraries, centos-6

On CentOS release 6.4, I am trying to run a binary. However, it gives the following complaint:

```
(...) requires "/lib/libuuid.so.1" to function.
```

From a quick search, I can see that the only similar file I have is the following:

```
/lib64/libuuid.so.1
```

After Googling around, I've found some people claiming that the libraries in 6.4 are "multi arch"; does this mean that you do no longer need separate libraries for 32 and 64 bit? Because when I try to install another version as per [this guide](http://www.aleach.com/libstdc-so-6-error-in-centos-6/) (which worked great for a similar libstdc error), it won't let me:

```
# yum install libuuid-2.17.2-12.9.el6.i686
(...)
Protected multilib versions: libuuid-2.17.2-12.9.el6.i686 != libuuid-2.17.2-12.9.el6_4.3.x86_64
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? Is the binary at fault for not detecting the multiarch/"multilib" library? Am I at fault for not providing a valid library? I'm a bit confused as you can probably tell.

Comment: Looks like we need not install libuuid.i686. Just remove it and install libuuid.

Comment: Just remove "it"? Please be more specific.

Comment: `yum remove libuuid.i686` and `yum install libuuid`

Comment: Please read the question more carefully, `libuuid.i686` was never installed.

Comment: Sorry then I think I didn't get this correctly. I was just fiddling around with something and this above step worked (removing i686 and installing standard). Might not be the same one as you.